# Table Alignment

Tags: html, html-table, valign

I have a list of hotels and their logos laid out in a table at:

http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/partner-hotels/

All the logos are in the left column and all the text in the right.

My problem is that the text is not aligning at the top of the cell next to the logo.

Any tips would help.

Here is some of my code:

```
<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><a title="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" href="http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com" target="_blank"><img class="wp-image-440 alignleft" title="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" alt="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" src="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/BIGcomfort-inn-logo.jpg" width="175" height="207" /></a></td>
<td valign="top">
<h3><b>Comfort Inn &amp; Suites-Rancho Cordova</b></h3>
<span style="font-size: small;">12249 Folsom Blvd., Rancho Cordova, CA</span>
<span style="font-size: small;"> <span style="line-height: 1.714285714;">Phone: 916-351-1213
</span><a style="line-height: 1.714285714; font-size: inherit;" href="http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com/">http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com</a></span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td valign="top"><a href="http://marriott.com/sacrc" target="_blank"><img class=" wp-image-455 alignleft" alt="Courtyard Marriott" src="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cy_logo.png" width="175" height="175" /></a></td>
<td valign="top">
<h3><span style="font-size: medium;"><b>Courtyard by Marriott-Rancho Cordova</b></span></h3>
<span style="font-size: small;">10683 White Rock Rd., Rancho Cordova, CA</span>
<span style="font-size: small;"> <span style="line-height: 1.714285714;">Phone: 916-638-3800
</span><a style="line-height: 1.714285714; font-size: inherit;" href="http://marriott.com/sacrc">http://marriott.com/sacrc</a></span></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the following css property for all the text rows:

```
float:right;
```

Comment: Thank you! It works but still have a few that are out of alignment. Will double check my code.

Answer (score 0):

That is due to header tag

#### ...

```
try this code. i've used <div> tag applied styles for Font size instead of <h3>

 <table border="0">

                    <tr>
                        <td><a title="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" href="http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com" target="_blank">
                            <img class="wp-image-440 alignleft" title="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" alt="Comfort Inn &amp; Suites" src="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/BIGcomfort-inn-logo.jpg" width="175" height="207" /></a></td>
                        <td>
                            <div style="font-size:large"><b>Comfort Inn &amp; Suites-Rancho Cordova</b></div>
                            <span style="font-size: small;">12249 Folsom Blvd., Rancho Cordova, CA</span>
                            <span style="font-size: small;"><span style="line-height: 1.714285714;">Phone: 916-351-1213
                            </span><a style=" font-size: inherit;" href="http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com/">http://www.comfortinnandsuitesrc.com</a></span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a href="http://marriott.com/sacrc" target="_blank">
                            <img class=" wp-image-455 alignleft" alt="Courtyard Marriott" src="http://ranchocordovaeventscenter.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/cy_logo.png" width="175" height="175" /></a></td>
                        <td>
                            <h3><span style="font-size: medium;"><b>Courtyard by Marriott-Rancho Cordova</b></span></h3>
                            <span style="font-size: small;">10683 White Rock Rd., Rancho Cordova, CA</span>
                            <span style="font-size: small;"><span style="line-height: 1.714285714;">Phone: 916-638-3800
                            </span><a style="line-height: 1.714285714; font-size: inherit;" href="http://marriott.com/sacrc">http://marriott.com/sacrc</a></span></td>
                    </tr>

            </table>
```